# how to search for an element using the queryselector and contains

Tags: javascript, contains, queryselector

Somehow I would like to search directly for some text?
Is that possible using querySelector?

Dom :

```
<div class="div1">
    <span class="text">
        <span> text to search </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I have tried the following without success.

JS Code: `document.querySelector('div[contains("text to")]')` = FAIL

I know the easy way something like: `document.querySelector('span.text > span')` 
My example is kept simple, I know that. I am looking for a solution similar to selenium `selenium driver.find_element_by_link_text`
I want to independently search for an element without relying on the class or id, any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS selector for elements containing certain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text)

Comment: This didn't answer my question, but it was very helpfully. Thanks (=

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with `querySelector` directly. You have to fetch all spans first and then iterate over them to see which one has the text you want. For example:

```
var results = []; 
document.querySelector("span").forEach(elem => {
    if (elem.textContent.includes("text to")) {
        results.push(elem);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, so i had a similar result, but i was on hopinig there is simple alternative. (=